# error #1009 addChld() as3 with loop

Tags: class, loops, actionscript-3, game-loop

when i try to addChild my class it says
"Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at class_obj() at Main()" error #1009

i need to know how to have a class that has a gameloop
for testing things like collision and stuff please help!

and if i dont have eventlistener enter frame on the object ir works
but i need the listener for the loop.

Main class

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        var mc:class_obj;

        public function Main()
        {
            //constructor
            mc = new class_obj();
            addChild(mc);
        }
    }
}
```

object class

```
package  
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class class_obj extends MovieClip 
    {

        public function class_obj() 
        {
            // constructor code
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }
        public function loop(e:Event)
        {
            trace("LOOPED CLASS");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also note that in AS3 we use [PascalCase](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase) for class names - `ClassObj` is preferred over `class_ob`j so it is easily distinguishable what type of property we deal with.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid any issue in your loop if you have some references to the Stage Object, I think That @Pawel is right when he say that "You need to first listen for :

```
Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE
```

So upvote for Pawel!

Each Class name should start with an Uppercase letter as he said, and it's a good practice to remove an Event Listener when You don't need it anymore.

So Your classes should be :

Main :

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import ClassObj;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        var mc:ClassObj;

        public function Main() {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,addClip);
        }

        private function addClip(e:Event):void {
            trace("Class Main instance is added to : " + this.parent);
            mc = new ClassObj();
            addChild(mc);
            e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,addClip);
            trace(this + "hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE) = " + e.target.hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE));
        }
    }

}
```

and ClassObj :

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class ClassObj extends MovieClip {

        public function ClassObj() {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,checkClip);
        }

        private function checkClip(e:Event):void{
            trace("ClassObj instance is added to : " + this.parent);
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,checkClip);
            trace(this + "hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE) = " + e.target.hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE));
        }

        private function loop(e:Event):void{
             trace("LOOPED CLASS Stage is : " + e.target.stage);
             trace("LOOPED CLASS parent is : " + e.target.parent);
        }
    }

}
```

Output will be :

```
Class Main instance is added to : [object Stage]
ClassObj instance is added to : [object Main]
[object ClassObj]hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE) = false
[object Main]hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE) = false
LOOPED CLASS Stage is : [object Stage]
LOOPED CLASS parent is : [object Main]
LOOPED CLASS Stage is : [object Stage]
LOOPED CLASS parent is : [object Main]
```

...

[EDIT] Here is a useful link to understand ADDED and ADDED_TO_STAGE :

http://fromzerotoas3hero.blogspot.be/2011/03/added-vs-addedtostage.html

[/EDIT]

Comment: Did you considered putting this in documentation? There is no `ADDED_TO_STAGE` example

Comment: The comments are now disabled on the Adobe website. @Pawel
But You may find a lot of documentation on the web about ADDED and ADDED_TO_STAGE

Comment: I was thinking about SO documentation.

Comment: @Paweł  Here is a short example (short and efficient to understand the two events).
http://fromzerotoas3hero.blogspot.be/2011/03/added-vs-addedtostage.html

Comment: @Pawel my PC is completely inefficient since the Window 10 build 1703 and I'm not able to install the build 1709.
So this is why I'm no more active on this community :(
I'm waiting for an Apple that a friend is using. So, I think to jump to swift :) Thank You and happy New Year!

Comment: I don't know what it has to do with the question. I have Win 7 on 8 yo machine and it still works decently :). In my work I have 4 months laptop with Win 10 and it works horrible when compiling big C# project... But thanks and happy new year for You to :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have access to the stage (this is only object that you use so no other can be null obviously.

You need to first listen for

```
Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE
```

because movieclip has no access to stage before it's added to display list.

**Edit**

In your simple case you don't event need to use use stage object. You can listen for frame event on your class_object instance itself:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
```

Comment: @Indy FYI, please try to fix other aspects of the post, when possible, if suggesting edits removing Docs links.